# Simple timer circuit for LED

Tags: timer

I have a hopefully simple question. I have 4.5 V battery-operated LED decoration that I want to turn on for 5 hours and turn off for 19, give or take an hour or so. Accuracy is not important.

Currently the circuit consists of LEDs, batteries and a couple of different resistors. I have LED candles that do this and appear very simple but can't figure out what controls the timing in such a small package. I suppose I could "cannibalize" the candle for the circuit, but I would really like to understand how the timing is being controlled.

Comment: Small [COB MCU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tsjo4.png) in all likelihood for those things that "appear very simple." In the LED candles, they probably don't even need to go that far since they can bury the whole thing inside the LED encapsulation. You probably won't get to do a one-off like that. You'll have to do your own MCU.

Comment: This would be a fairly easy project for a low cost 8 pin micro-controller. Search for projects such as electronic birthday candle control circuit. A little adjustment of the code can get you what you need.  Here are two one examples: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1278145/LED-Candle-Light-with-Timer .  . https://michaelteeuw.nl/post/the-fire-proof-birthday-candle/

Comment: A free-running counter fed with oscillator. Put gates on counter output to obtain timing you want.